# How can I create a setter method for a new object with default values?

Tags: ruby, setter

In my test file, I have:

```
def default_product()
  Product.new(title: "default title",
              description: "default description",
              price:       1,
              image_url:   'default_url.png')
end
```

and would like to turn it into a method that can be called either without args, in which case the default attrs would be set, or with args, such as:

```
default_product(price: 100)
```

in which case the default price would be overridden by the argument.

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot)?

Comment: Not at all, only because I wasn't aware of it until now + as a newbie trying to keep things as simple as possible. I shall try it out.

Comment: It's definitely the tool for the job. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of default keyword parameters:

```
def default_product(
    title: "default title",
    description: "default description",
    price: 1,
    image_url: 'default_url.png')
  Product.new(
    title: title,
    description: description,
    price: price,
    image_url: image_url)
end
```

And call it like: `default_product(title: "Another title")`.

---

*Sidenote:* the proper approach would be probably to use [`FactoryBot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot).

Comment: That works great and will have a look at FactoryBot.